# date() function timestramp returns wrong date

Tags: php, json, date, epoch

When I give the timestamp argument to php date() the incorrect date is returned. Formatting is correct, however the result is not as expected.

src is from Hubspot json.

```
public 'publish_date' => int 1438079400000

$feed = (object) $this->json;
    $string = '';

    if( $feed->total_count > 0):
        foreach( $feed->objects as $item ):
            $item = (object) $item;
            date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
            ob_start();

            ?>
            <?php echo date( 'l jS F Y', $item->publish_date ); ?>
            <?php

            $string .= ob_get_clean();

        endforeach;
    endif;

    return $string;
```

Results in **Sunday 14th April 47546**

Epoch Converter check says timestamp is **Thu, 30 Jul 2015 09:30:00 GMT**

Using date() without the timestamp returns the correct date for today.

Comment: echo date( 'l jS F Y',1438079400000);    Saturday 21st September 1946 5:10:am

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to divide the date by 1000.

1438079400000 -> 14380794000

```
php > echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 1438079400000);
47540-12-03 12:00:00
php > echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 1438079400);
2015-07-28 11:30:00
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a reason for the extra granularity in this integer from Hubspot?

Comment: Sorry, I actually meant with regards to the timestamp, why have the additional '0000' when milliseconds is granular enough.

Comment: Epoch is in seconds, that was in milliseconds.